# 'Philosophy' and 'Darshan' : are they same or different?

Tags: history-of-philosophy

As in India what we call 'Darshan' (दर्शन) in Sanskrit, it literally translate as "Visualization" or "Realisation".

The western term, "philosophy" literally means "Quest for knowledge".

Conventionally, "Darshan" is translated  in English as "Philosophy".

However; apparently there are some crude distinction between the Eastern "Darshan" and western "philosophy", as literary Pramatha Chowdhury (Pen name Birbal) once wrote "তোমাদের দার্শনিক খোঁজে যুক্তি; আমাদের দার্শনিক খোঁজে মুক্তি" (Your philosopher seeks logic ((literally translate to connection or addition)) and our philosophers seek Mukti ((Moksha/Nirvana/Samadhi/Escape)).

Indeed there are differences, like Western philosophy is much about a description and documentation of the reality and knowledge; whereas Eastern "Darshan" is more applied. Like how you do "Sadhana" (preparation of ones' self to reveal the obscure), often through a guided path of a Guru (Yogi/Ascetic), and inculcating the revealation into life.

Now my question is; is it just a mistranslation/Linguistic confusion? or the both subjects are basically same? or they are just different subsets of the same subject?

Personally I believe that Western philosophy too, including Epistemology and intuitive mathematics, require lot of "Sadhana", and different people evade a different level of realisation in Western philosophy too.

Comment: "Philosophy" literally translates as "love of wisdom", not "quest for knowledge", and it is neither (literally) as practiced today, although both serve as motivations. Etymology of names is generally not a reliable guide to the meaning. There are similar distinctions between theoretical and practical philosophy in the West as in the East. Shankara or Vaisheshika authors spend a lot of space on description and documentation of reality, while Plotinus on a path to enlightenment. It is fair to say that there is more emphasis on the latter in the Indian tradition, but both are heterogenous.

Comment: A more interesting question is [What is the difference between the philosophy practiced in India and the philosophy practiced outside?].

Answer (score 1):

Philosophy is better translated "love of wisdom". Most ancient cultures had a wisdom tradition, including the Greeks. Wisdom included history and mythology, how to get along with the gods, how to get along with rulers, how to get along with your neighbors, and how to live a peaceful and happy life. In Greece, it morphed into a competitive debate sport that was often an event along with physical games (that's what Socrates was criticizing when he said we should search for truth rather than try to win arguments). Euclid invented the axiomatic method in this environment, and I suspect part of the reason was that he wanted to avoid arguments and just pursue mathematics.

Inspired by mathematics and Socrates, Greek thought changed rather dramatically from a wisdom tradition to a tradition of seeking truth through rational investigation. Western philosophy inherited this tradition, and the large bulk of modern philosophy fits mostly into it, although one still sees work that harks back to wisdom literature (I'm thinking of *Zen and the Art of Motorcycle Maintenance* and *The Myth of Sisyphus*).

I'm not familiar with Indian Darshan, but from your comments, it seems more like wisdom literature than like Western philosophy.

Comment: Thank you. Indian tradition of Darshan can be classified into different paths like Samkhya, Yoga, etc.

Comment: I think it would be great to address the specificities of Indian Darshan. "Wisdom literature" sounds a bit reductive.

Answer (score 1):

The question whether “Philosophy” and “Darshana” are the same or are different cannot be answered in a few lines. Because the two concepts cover a wide range of meanings. As a consequence there is no general agreement about a precise definition of these terms, much less a basis for a precise answer.

- This fact is already obvious when asking for the definition of the term
  "philosophy" in European philosophy. The spectrum of answers spans from
  Existential Philosophy to Analytic Philosophy, from Metaphysics to
  the Frankfurt Schol of Critical Theory.
- Concerning Indian philosophy there are at least two corresponding
  candidates, darshana (दर्शन) and anviksiki (आन्वीक्षिकी).

  The
  former term “darshana” translates as “seeing, contemplating,
  doctrine”, and names the six Indian schools which consider themselves to be
  orthodox. The doctrine of these schools spans a spectrum from Nyaya
  with its strong emphasis on epistemology and logic to Vedanta, which
  focuses around the concepts of brahman and atman and favours the
  method of meditation.

  The latter term “anviksiki” translates as
  logic, logical philosophy, metaphysics. It covers approaches which
  propagate the critical method of questioning.
- From the etymological point of view neither “darshana” nor
  “anviksiki” can be equated with the word "philosophy" (love of wisdom).

Comment: Thank you for your effort and insight to this matter.

Comment: You are welcome.